# Как создать бесконечный цикл

Tags: c++, циклы

Как звучит задача:

Написать программу «справочник». Создать два одномерных массива. Один массив хранит номера ICQ, второй – телефонные номера. Реализовать меню для пользователя:

1.Отсортировать по номерам ICQ

2.Отсортировать по номерам телефона

3.Вывести список пользователей

4.Выход

Вопрос:

Всё, что я хотел реализовать - сделано, но вот goto мне не нравится и хотелось бы понять как обходиться без него.

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand(time(0));
    const int ICQ = 10;
    const int N = 10;
    int arr1[ICQ] = {};
    int arr2[N] = {};
    int num = 0;

tryAgain2:
    for (int i = 0; i < ICQ; i++) {
        arr1[i] = rand() % 101;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr2[i] = rand() % 90000000 + 9999999;
    }

tryAgain:
    cout << "№\t Номер телефона \t Номер ICQ" << endl;
    cout << "1.\t   " << arr2[0] << "\t\t    " << arr1[0] << endl;
    cout << "2.\t   " << arr2[1] << "\t\t    " << arr1[1] << endl;
    cout << "3.\t   " << arr2[2] << "\t\t    " << arr1[2] << endl;
    cout << "4.\t   " << arr2[3] << "\t\t    " << arr1[3] << endl;
    cout << "5.\t   " << arr2[4] << "\t\t    " << arr1[4] << endl;
    cout << "6.\t   " << arr2[5] << "\t\t    " << arr1[5] << endl;
    cout << "7.\t   " << arr2[6] << "\t\t    " << arr1[6] << endl;
    cout << "8.\t   " << arr2[7] << "\t\t    " << arr1[7] << endl;
    cout << "9.\t   " << arr2[8] << "\t\t    " << arr1[8] << endl;
    cout << "10.\t   " << arr2[9] << "\t\t    " << arr1[9] << endl;


    cout << "\n1.\t Отсортировать по номерам ICQ" << endl;
    cout << "2.\t Отсортировать по номерам телефона" << endl;
    cout << "3.\t Вывести список пользователей" << endl;
    cout << "4.\t Выход" << endl << endl;
    cin >> num;

    switch (num)
    {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        for (int i = 1; i < ICQ; ++i)
        {
            int k = i;
            while (k > 0 && arr1[k - 1] > arr1[k])
            {
                int tmp = arr1[k - 1];
                arr1[k - 1] = arr1[k];
                arr1[k] = tmp;
                tmp = arr2[k - 1];
                arr2[k - 1] = arr2[k];
                arr2[k] = tmp;
                k -= 1;
            }
        }

        goto tryAgain;

    case 2:
        system("cls");
        for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        {
            int k = i;
            while (k > 0 && arr2[k - 1] > arr2[k])
            {
                int tmp = arr2[k - 1];
                arr2[k - 1] = arr2[k];
                arr2[k] = tmp;
                tmp = arr1[k - 1];
                arr1[k - 1] = arr1[k];
                arr1[k] = tmp;
                k -= 1;
            }
        }

        goto tryAgain;

    case 3:
        system("cls");

        goto tryAgain2;
        break;
    case 4:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если у вас по смыслу задачи массивы `arr1[ICQ]` (для номеров ICQ) и `arr2[N]` (для номеров телефонов) должны быть одного размера (а иначе в печати таблицы будет ерунда), то и задавайте размер этих массивов **одной константой** (например, `N_USERS`), а не 2-мя как у вас сейчас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сами по себе `goto` убираются легко. Для более изящной программы надо как-то перерабатывать алгоритм, а просто эквивалентное преобразование в `for` будет выглядеть так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

constexpr int ICQ = 10;
constexpr int N = 10;

void Reinit(int arr1[], int arr2[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ICQ; i++) {
    arr1[i] = rand() % 101;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    arr2[i] = rand() % 90000000 + 9999999;
  }
}

int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
  srand((unsigned)time(0));
  int arr1[ICQ];
  int arr2[N];
  int num = 0;

  Reinit(arr1, arr2);

  for (;;) {
    cout << "№\t Номер телефона \t Номер ICQ" << endl;
    cout << "1.\t   " << arr2[0] << "\t\t    " << arr1[0] << endl;
    cout << "2.\t   " << arr2[1] << "\t\t    " << arr1[1] << endl;
    cout << "3.\t   " << arr2[2] << "\t\t    " << arr1[2] << endl;
    cout << "4.\t   " << arr2[3] << "\t\t    " << arr1[3] << endl;
    cout << "5.\t   " << arr2[4] << "\t\t    " << arr1[4] << endl;
    cout << "6.\t   " << arr2[5] << "\t\t    " << arr1[5] << endl;
    cout << "7.\t   " << arr2[6] << "\t\t    " << arr1[6] << endl;
    cout << "8.\t   " << arr2[7] << "\t\t    " << arr1[7] << endl;
    cout << "9.\t   " << arr2[8] << "\t\t    " << arr1[8] << endl;
    cout << "10.\t   " << arr2[9] << "\t\t    " << arr1[9] << endl;


    cout << "\n1.\t Отсортировать по номерам ICQ" << endl;
    cout << "2.\t Отсортировать по номерам телефона" << endl;
    cout << "3.\t Вывести список пользователей" << endl;
    cout << "4.\t Выход" << endl << endl;
    cin >> num;

    switch (num)
    {
      case 1:
        system("cls");
        for (int i = 1; i < ICQ; ++i)
        {
          int k = i;
          while (k > 0 && arr1[k - 1] > arr1[k])
          {
            int tmp = arr1[k - 1];
            arr1[k - 1] = arr1[k];
            arr1[k] = tmp;
            tmp = arr2[k - 1];
            arr2[k - 1] = arr2[k];
            arr2[k] = tmp;
            k -= 1;
          }
        }
        break;

      case 2:
        system("cls");
        for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        {
          int k = i;
          while (k > 0 && arr2[k - 1] > arr2[k])
          {
            int tmp = arr2[k - 1];
            arr2[k - 1] = arr2[k];
            arr2[k] = tmp;
            tmp = arr1[k - 1];
            arr1[k - 1] = arr1[k];
            arr1[k] = tmp;
            k -= 1;
          }
        }
        break;

      case 3:
        system("cls");
        Reinit(arr1, arr2);
        break;

      case 4:
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Мелкие замечания:

1) Для `srand` надо делать каст `time_t`.

2) Массивы при объявлении инициализировать не нужно, они будут все равно инициализированы позже.

3) После `goto` не нужно ставить `break`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Благодаря вам я узнал о существовании "constexpr", про него более подробно сегодня почитаю. Замечания обязательно учту. Будьте добры, поясните вот это: void Reinit(int arr1[], int arr2[]) Reinit(arr1, arr2);   Также не совсем понял про "time_t" как и где использовать?

Comment: @Blacit, - 1) `Reinit` - это я просто вынес кусочек кода в функцию чтобы убрать вторую метку. Иначе получались два пересекающихся блока, и в простой цикл это не помещалось. 2) `time_t` - функция `time` возвращает результат типа `time_t`, а `srand` требует аргумент типа `unsigned int`. Без явного каста компилятор выдает предупреждение.

Comment: Не можете подсказать как добавить, чтобы ещё имена пользователей перемещались с телефонами и icq. И как можно сохранить исходную информацию по массивам, чтобы нажав кнопку 3 - у нас выдавалась первоначальная таблица, которая была создана с самого начала.

Comment: Вот тут у меня сохранён код (самый первый(актуальный)): [ссылка](https://gist.github.com/Blacit/1ba0fe32c1df752403a3984dee90e05e)

Comment: @Blacit, ну, переписать вам программу я не могу, просто времени нет, но могу подсказать направление. Вам нужно использовать С++ (сюрприз:).  Во-первых, определите `struct`, которая будет описывать пользователя - имя, телефон, все дела. Потом создайте один единственный `vector`, который будет хранить эти структуры. А для сортировки используйте алгоритм `std::sort`. Программа у вас станет лучше, проще, и раза так в четыре меньше.

Comment: По программе мы ещё не можем использовать всё то, что находится позже массивов про программе обучения) Даже функции ещё не знаем. А сам c++ уж подавно) Пока что только СИ...

Comment: @Blacit, тогда откуда у вас `<iostream>` и `cout <<`? Это С++. Тогда уж используйте `printf`. Ну неважно - в С есть структуры и это главное, что вам нужно. Делайте структуру, и один массив этих структур. А для сортировки используйте функцию С `qsort`. Не так удобно как на С++, но все равно будет сильно лучше.

Comment: Хотелось бы ещё раз к вам обратиться) По вашему предложению, начал изучать структуры, вектор и std::sort, пока первое и последнее начал проходить, вот то, что получилось: [ссылка](https://gist.github.com/Blacit/b6741457fa4fa3b59b21710904714874) Не понимаю почему switch не хочет реагировать.

Comment: @Blacit, что значит "не хочет реагировать"? Он у вас вообще закомментирован, какой реакции от него вы ждете?

Comment: Я ведь закомментировал, чтобы можно было попробовать без него. Если раскомментировать, то ошибка где-то в std::sort, как правильно будет его в данном случае использовать, чтобы отсортировать телефонные номера, icqs и именам, но только, чтобы всё это было связано?

Comment: @Blacit, `std::sort` требует задать функцию сравнения, потому что структура это составной тип, для которого не существует стандартной функции сравнения. Что-нибудь вроде `std::sort(people, people + n, [](person p1, person p2) {return p1.phones < p2.phone;});`. Вообще если вы используете массивы в стиле C, то лучше использовать `qsort`, а не `std::sort`. Пытаться использовать куски STL без понимания что делается - ничего хорошего в результате не выйдет.

Comment: Благодарен вам за фактический готовый код самой программы :З Ключевой момент уж точно. Честно скажу, что не разобрался в std::sort(people, people + n, [](person p1, person p2) {return p1.phones < p2.phone;});  Ещё не проходил такое, но использовал, попробую изучить самостоятельно, но на данном этапе - прошёл только массивы. Код, который сделан: [ссылка](https://gist.github.com/Blacit/b6741457fa4fa3b59b21710904714874)

Answer (score 0):

`for(;;)` - это и есть бесконечный цикл. Банальный ответ, но всё же.

Comment: Спасибо большое :) Выше предоставили код целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть два варианта, используйте тот, который вам по душе:

1. `for(;;)`
2. `while(1)`

Чтобы выйти из бесконечного цикла следует прописать `break;`.